# Getting data from a JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Sorry for the messy name of the question, this is my first SQL one.

Does anyone know how to get the `OrderID` of an Order where the max quantity of a product was sold?

This is my code by far:

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, MAX([Order Details].Quantity), MAX(OrderID)
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
GROUP BY Products.ProductName
```

When I say `MAX(OrderID)` I get the Highest ID where the product was sold, not the actual ID where the Highest quantity of the product was sold.

This is my first question about SQL, Sorry for any lack of information, just tell me what is needed and I'll add it. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are you getting an error when you attempt to run it, or just 0 records returned?

Comment: How do you decide which OrderId to report in the case of ties?

Comment: I'm getting the wrong results. I'm getting the highest ID instead of the actual ID where the  MAX([Order Details].Quantity) grouped by Product name is located.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.ProductName, [Order Details].OrderID, [Order Details].Qty 
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID 
WHERE [Order Details].Quantity = (SELECT MAX(p.Quantity) FROM [Order Details] p WHERE p.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
```

Note: this will give you multiple results for a single product, if you have multiple orders with max quantity ordered.

Comment: I think this will work in mySQL, but not sure about other variants since OrderID in the select clause is not part of an aggregate.

Comment: Try using Max(OrderID) and see if the error goes away, the syntax above works in mySQL

Comment: That's exactly the error. Anyway to solve this? I'm using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that you are using sql server. Will update my answer shortly

Comment: @Sparky: This will compile in MySQL, but likely not work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use analytical functions for this:

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT ProductName, Quantity, OrderID
FROM (  SELECT  Products.ProductName, [Order Details].Quantity, OrderID, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Products.ProductName ORDER BY [Order Details].Quantity DESC) Corr
        FROM Products 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID) A
WHERE Corr = 1
```

This way you will get only one record per Product, that means that if you have more than one Order with the same max quantity, you are only getting one as result. You can add more columns (order date for example) on the `ORDER BY` to choose the newest or oldest of those. If you want to get all the records that are tied on the quantity, then you can use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT ProductName, Quantity, OrderID
FROM (  SELECT  Products.ProductName, [Order Details].Quantity, OrderID, 
                RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Products.ProductName ORDER BY [Order Details].Quantity DESC) Corr
        FROM Products 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID) A
WHERE Corr = 1
```

Comment: It worked but to be honest I'm just a begginner and I don't understand most of this code. I apologize.

Comment: But how do you handle ties?   If a given product has two or more orders with the same quantity, won't this query only report the first one?

Comment: @Sparky - Yes, it returns just one record, since its what op was getting with the `max` query. For ties, you can use `RANK` as @Andriy said, and it will return all record with the same quantity, I don't know if that's what op wants or not

Comment: I think that is why I bring up the ties issue, your answer works fine, but if the op doesn't consider ties, he could ignoring information he might need.   I would if SQL would consistently return the same order number in the event of a tie, or could the query optimizer actually produce different results in ordering when a tie occurs...

Comment: @Sparky - Thanks for the concern, I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini - There is no need for you to apologize, you can choose whatever answer helped you the most, its all good :-)